# What does にございます mean in this line?

Tags: translation

Here's the line:

> この光は、本物の太陽の光、地上より導きいれた聖なる光にございます

I would translate it something like this: "This light, genuine solar light, is holy light let in from the surface". I ignored the に, so I assume that interpretation isn't correct. What's being said here and how does it work?

Comment: Hint: You cannot just ignore the に and pretend it is not there.  You must replace it by another particle for understanding and translating.  Another hint: http://livedoor.blogimg.jp/labitgame-monsoku/imgs/6/2/62ab6b3d.jpg  What particle would you replace the に in the image with to make it "easier" for you or other J-learners?

Comment: Looks like で would be most appropriate, but then why use に? Is it more formal or old-fashioned or something?

Comment: @FinS Yes, you're right! You replace it with で, and に is more formal and old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has its origin in the roots of the modern copular verb だ. Classical Japanese had two main copular verbs たり and なり, the latter of which remains as the な in things like 綺麗**な**花 or そう**な**んだ or 行く**なら**. These two copular verbs can further be broken down as とあり and にあり, the latter of which can also become **に**てあり　→　である →　**で**ござる. This structure also "often" comes up in things like ～ことにあり・にあらず。